# I am using react-webcam but when camera to take a picture, it always shows 0.5 zoom and blurred

Tags: reactjs

i am using react-webcam but when i use my phone camera to take a picture, it always shows 0.5 zoom and blurred. I want to show clearly, without blur and 1x zoom. I tried but failed. i need your help. Has anyone come across such a case?

Comment: please provide code sample.